# strings of array dynammicaly created not working

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

Why this code not working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char **orderedIds;
    orderedIds = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        orderedIds[i] = malloc((10) * sizeof(char));
        char name[10];
        printf("Enter name %d: \n",i);
        scanf("%s",&name);
        orderedIds[i] = name;
        printf("%s\n",orderedIds[i]);
    }
    printf("element is %s\n",orderedIds[0]);
}
```

Every element is the last element in the array i dont know why its not working plz help this is the output

```
Enter name 0:
john
john
Enter name 1:
guy
guy
Enter name 2:
some
some
element is some
```

some should be the last element but its the first why?

Comment: `orderedIds[i] = name;` - you are assigning a pointer to an array that only exists within the current loop iteration. It goes out of scope when the iteration ends (and you also leak the `malloc`d memory)

Comment: i dont understood can you tell the right code for it?

Comment: @Lundin yeah, I shouldn't have done it, I see it now. Revoting to close.

Comment: @Lundin can't find the dupe, I let you close vote again.... sorry

Comment: @Lundin I just cvd again and now it's OK. Sorry, I suggest we delete the comments regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing shallow copying which means you are assigning two pointers to the same memory location so that they are both affected if one of them changes the pointed value state. See the shallow copy [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy#:%7E:text=What%20is%20Shallow%20Copy%3F,the%20memory%20address%20is%20copied.)

How to solve it? You need to do deep copying. Luckily, there is a built-in function in string.h library for that purpose. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char **orderedIds;
    orderedIds = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        orderedIds[i] = malloc((10) * sizeof(char));
        char name[10];
        printf("Enter name %d: \n",i);
        scanf("%s",&name);
        strcpy(orderedIds[i], name);
        printf("%s\n",orderedIds[i]);
    }
    printf("element is %s\n",orderedIds[0]);
}
```